# Bokeh slider with CustomJS callback fails to use callback_policy='mouseup' option

Tags: python, flask, bokeh

I am trying to create a simple **flask** graphical app using **bokeh** for plotting. My code uses the **json_item** function to embed a plot into an html page and is based on the bokeh [example](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/tree/1.1.0/examples/embed/json_item.py).To control plot parameters, I have just added two sliders, for which I have set the option `callback_policy='mouseup'`. However, when I drag any of the sliders, it produces multiple plots instead of one plot. I am using the latest bokeh version 1.1.0.

I have searched web on that topic, but it looks that people have no such the problem with `callback_policy='mouseup'`. Probably, it does not work in my specific setup or I have an error, which I cannot catch.
My python **app.py** code is [here](https://pastebin.com/DfjYHVjm) and **index.html** from **templates** folder is [here](https://pastebin.com/JNPQru2t).
 I will be very grateful for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Bokeh versions 1.1 and earlier, the `callback_policy` only applies to the old-style `callback` property of the `Slider`, not the newer generic `js_on_change` methods. So you should be doing this:

```
fs.callback = cbk
ss.callback = cbk
```

However, in the upcoming release of Bokeh, things have been improved and clarified. The above method will continue to work (until Bokeh 2.0), but the recommended way to do things will be to watch the new `value_throttled` property:

```
# use this for version 1.2 and later:

fs.js_on_change('value_throttled', cbk)
ss.js_on_change('value_throttled', cbk)
```

Note that in the new method above will work for both JS callbacks, and now also for python callbacks in Bokeh server apps (with `on_change` of `js_on_change` instead, of course).